# Override the directory of .pro.user file of QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

In the past I thought that `.pro` files that QtCreator generates are specific to it so I put it in `/IDE/QtCreator` subdirectory of my projects. But when I learned the `.pro` file is just a script for `qmake` I realized that it is not specific to QtCreator.

Now I want to put the `.pro` file in the root directory of my project but QtCreator generates `.pro.user` file in the same directory and I really don't want to put IDE specific files in the root directory.

Is there a way to override a directory where QtCreator places `.pro.user` files?

I've found a `-settingspath` command line argument but I want to put it in some config file so it'll work when I double click on the `.pro` file.

Comment: just delete *.pro.user file in new folder

Comment: @Edward, but that would reset my QtCreator settings which I don't want to lose.